# asp.net MVC 4 webapi authentication for IOS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I need to implement authentication in my webapi. Is any one know how to do that like link to the code that is authenticating  asp.net mvc4 web api for IOS .

Kindly provide me the link or data so that i can implement it accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: try http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793845/authenticating-asp-net-web-api