# Web API - Authentication Advice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Background:
- Using Web API in a Web Forms app with ASP.Net 4.0/C# using VS 2012
- Some pages will use Web API calls with JQuery, others will use web forms postbacks

Need to do the following:

- Have user login with username/password
- Validate credentials with SQL Server DB
- Generate token back to client
- Have client use token to authenticate on future API requests
- Maintain user session regardless if using Web API or web form postback

What I'm not clear about is:

- How to generate token using Web API
- How to validate the token server-side on each call (store in SQL Server?)
- How to maintain user session with a mix of Web API/web form postbacks

Answer (score 1):

I have used Thinktecture IdentityModel from http://thinktecture.github.io/.
It is a great library which includes token generation.

This is the original article I referred to when I was implementing it

http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/dog-fooding-our-api-authentication

I also did some write up on my blog if you are interested

http://sunilrav.com/post/Enable-Basic-Authetication-in-Aspnet-webapi-using-ThinktectureIdentityModel

http://sunilrav.com/post/Enable-CORS-in-Aspnet-webapi-using-ThinktectureIdentityModel

This post helped me when I was doing my research

[REST service authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996673/rest-service-authentication)